# Angular $watch not updating bindings

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to provide default values for some model properties, and am trying to accomplish this using $watches. I can't use the ordinary 2 way binding as I need the model properties to initially be empty. However, while my $watches are setting the properties ok, the HTML that is bound to them isn't getting updated.

```
<!doctype html>
<body ng-app="TestApp" ng-controller="TestCtrl">
    <div><input ng-model="form.firstname" placeholder="enter your first name"/></div>
    <div><input ng-model="form.lastname" placeholder="enter your last name"/></div>    
    <p>{{user.firstname}}</p>
    <p>{{user.lastname}}</p>
</body>

angular.module('TestApp', [])
.controller('TestCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {

    $scope.user = new User({
        firstname: 'Bruce',
        lastname: 'Wayne'
    });

    function User(defaults) {
        angular.extend(this, defaults);
        $scope.form = {};

        angular.forEach(this, function(value, key) {
            $scope.form[key] = '';

            $scope.$watch(function() {
                return $scope.form[key];
            }, function (val) {
                this[key] = val || defaults[key];
                console.log(val)
                console.log(defaults[key])
                console.log(this[key])
            });
        });
    }
}]);
```

See a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/leeellam/ysos7yoh/) - what I want is for any value entered in the box to be reflected in the text, and then if the value is deleted, for the default text to show up again. If you check the console, you'll see that the watch callback is working properly. I did try to wrap the update in $apply but got $digest in progress error.

Fairly new to angular, so am probably going the wrong way about trying to accomplish this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `this` changes while the `$watch`er runs.

```
    function User(defaults) {
        angular.extend(this, defaults);
        $scope.form = {};

        var self = this; // <-- Saving `this`.

        angular.forEach(this, function(value, key) {
            $scope.form[key] = '';

            $scope.$watch(function() {
                return $scope.form[key];
            }, function (val) {
                self[key] = val || defaults[key];
                console.log(val)
                console.log(defaults[key])
                console.log(self[key])
            });
        });
```

Saving `this` solves the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/637yypz1/1/